# Passing Parameters to a crystal Report dynamically

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am developing a windows application using vb.net. I have a requirement to print the **'Createdby**' in the Report Footer of the crystal report. This CreatedBy is a Parameter Field, which I retrieve from the database and pass through the code behind. In case the CreatedBy is Null, I want to display the **'PrintedBy'** i.e the current User Name in the report footer.I want it in the following format like:

Created By: **?CreatedBy** else Printed by:**?PrintedBy**

How can i achieve that? Since the Created By and Printed By are already the parameter field, if i don't pass them it will prompt the user to enter, which is not what I wanted. Also at the same time, i don't want to show both the parameter fields.

Please help me.

Many Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
// {@footer}
If Not(Isnull({?CreatedBy})) Then {?CreatedBy}
Else If Not(Isnull({?PrinteddBy})) Then {?PrintedBy}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the parameters as optional, this will require some special handling when you run the report from your code. The formula inside the report will look like this:

```
If HasValue({?CreatedBy}) Then {?CreatedBy}
Else If  HasValue({?PrinteddBy}) Then {?PrinteddBy}
Else 'Unknown'
```

In order to test this in Crystal designer you will need Crystal Reports 2008 or above.